# Send Email in Real Time with Asp.Net Web APi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-web-api, real-time

I have a web application (Asp Net MVC and WebApi), where I have an agenda that when creating an event in it, I can mark to receive a reminder of it by email ... That is where the problem is, I need a method in WebApi that stays active all day and when you miss 30 minutes for the event, send an email reminding ...

Since I have no idea how to do this, I've been looking for an intenet, and I've seen something about SignalR and Rx .NET ... Are these really useful for this problem? Is there any more technology that can do this !?

Comment: I think your question is possibly too vague, however it sounds more like you want a service that checks for upcoming events and emails participants when they are due to start. Since it's a web app I'd suggest looking into something like Hangfire https://www.hangfire.io/ or the new HostedService stuff in .net core https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-2-ihostedservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET, like many Web Server technologies, is not designed to perform this kind of real time tasks. Even if possible with some quirks, it's possible to run into many issues. A server could restart any time, run on a cluster etc.

I can give you a suggestion how we tend to solve things like that.

It appears that you might not need "real time" accuracy, maybe it would be enough to have an interval hitting every 1 minute (or even 5 minutes) and send all e-Mails which are due at this point in time, example:

```
// Of course, I don't know where your Data is coming from etc... asume some services doing that
public ActionResult SendDueEMails()
{
   // Query everything older then 30 minutes...
   var dueEMails = SomeReminderRepository.GetReminders();
   foreach (var dueEMail in dueEMails)
   {
       // Process sending of e-Mails
       EMailService.SendReminder(dueEMail);
   }

   return Content(dueEMails.Count + " e-Mails sent.");
}
```

Then, you could have some externally configured Task (tons of possibilities here) which is requesting this URL every 1 minute.

It's not realtime, it's more scheduled, but it would solve your problem.

Comment: I agree with you that you may not have to stay in real time, but at a certain interval.

 But how can I make this service run
even when the application is not open? Because I'm going to use this service for a mobile application too ...

Comment: Assume, the URL above resolves to: http://mysuperbapp.example.com/Home/SendDueEMails so what you could do is for example, register for a free Online Monitoring service like https://www.pingdom.com/free or https://uptimerobot.com/ and there, you can configure that URL to be triggered every x minutes, and it will do so, 24/7